# Docker for windows: real container IP different from the one shown on the configuration

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows

I've just started playing with docker and I'm facing a real strange issue. After installing, I've pulled an IIS nanoserver image and I've started it:

```
λ  docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
beabe561852f        d4                  "C:\\ServiceMonitor.e…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:81->80/tcp   nano-server
```

After that I've tried to access the site through the http://localhost:81. Since it wasn't working, I've inspected the IP with the following command:

```
λ  docker inspect -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks}}" b
{"nat":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":null,"NetworkID":"11117ac2f84721d1ca93c719192dd4d2aa5f9e6d23e7b3077dfd8ffb63aaf2e2","EndpointID":"68984bc164035e4035af1878673dda69e913dde19d641943cb68f7121aa9dae6","Gateway":"172.23.160.1","IPAddress":"172.23.174.235","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"00:15:5d:33:81:0a","DriverOpts":null}}
```

Pinging wasn't working either:

```
λ  ping 172.23.174.235

Pinging 172.23.174.235 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.200.2.222: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 10.200.2.222: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 10.200.2.222: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 10.200.2.222: Destination net unreachable.

Ping statistics for 172.23.174.235:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

So, I've tried running powershell in the container to check the IP:

```
PS C:\> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : mshome.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14e3:fd95:19a:c89b%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.238.55
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.160.1
                                       192.168.238.49
PS C:\>
```

As you can see, the container's "real" IP is completely different from the one that docker think it's being used by it.

I've already tried disconnecting the container from the network and reconnecting it again, but the results are always the same.

Any clues on what's going on here? Even more important, any tips on how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I've removed all unused networks with the docker network prune command. After deleting the Default Switch, everything started to work out correctly. I'm not sure on why this was required, but probably there was something wrong with that switch configuration...